# How to track changes url of UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have trouble with UIWebView.
Firsly i load web-page from request. When i ckicked any link in this web-page, UIWebView redrect to this link.
How can I track url changes of UIWebView?

Answer (score 2):

You should define `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` delegate method, e.g.:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:@"http"]) {
     ...

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate of UIWebView

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType
{
    NSLog(@"Redirecting to URL: %@", inRequest.URL.absoluteString);
    return YES;
}
```